# Nuget package restore not respecting my repository path configuration?

Tags: nuget

I have the following setup in my solution's `.nuget/Nuget.Config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <solution>
    <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
  </solution>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="C:\Xos\packages\" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

The point of this is to try and make Nuget package restore manageable, and share packages across our many solutions.  I then went into my current solution's packages directory and deleted all the packages (so they would instead restore them to `C:\Xos\packages`).  I then closed VS 2012 and reloaded the solution and rebuilt.

However, all my packages are being restored in my solution's packages directory, NOT the directory specified in repositoryPath configuration.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with VS2015 RC. One of two things suddenly made it work:

(1) I checked-out the project file from source control, and **completely closed** Visual Studio (not just the solution).

(2) I edited the csproj file and noticed that the entry for `packages.config` had a `<SubType>Designer</SubType>` inner tag, which I removed.

I suspect it was the close-down of Visual Studio...

Comment: Restarting Visual Studio seemed to work for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be [a bug](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1990) and is fixed in 2.3 (which doesn't appear to be released yet).

Until then I modified my `Nuget.Targets` as described in that bug and using that for now.

Comment: I have this problem as well and it's driving me crazy. I have no .nuget folder nor a NuGet.targets file